# Apply Similar Questions Algorithm to Potential Duplicate Answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, duplicate-answers

When questions get popular, they often get a whole bunch of duplicate answers.

See this English.se question:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149318/what-is-newspaper-paper-called

Answer A:

> [It is often referred to as "stock", "pulp" or just plain **"newsprint"** at different stages of the business, anywhere from the mill to press and newsroom. (I do paginating/layout at a small paper.)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149321/41607)

Answer B:

> [Newspapers are printed on **"newsprint"**.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149320/41607)

Answer C:

> [When I was a child it was always called **"newsprint"** as in "news print" that was about 40 years ago, so I can't imagine that it would have changed much.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149339/41607)

Answer D:

> [Such paper is called **newsprint.**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149319/41607)

Answer A is the accepted answer with over 30 upvotes, but B-D all have 9 upvotes. They offer absolutely zero value over the original answer and supply no new information whatsoever. Answers like this sitting around on popular questions result in people thinking it is okay to parrot other answers and share your opinion even if it doesn't add any additional information or improve the quality of the question.

Part of the issue is that people are reluctant to downvote a correct answer even if it is a duplicate.

### Proposal

An algorithm like the one for 'Similar Questions' could check just the other answers on that question and see if there are similar words in there. When it detects a strikingly similar post (whatever threshold can be diddled on a per-site basis), it could give a nice warning and a link to an article explaining that answers should provide additional information and not just to say "me too" which would be better indicated with an upvote and/or a comment.

Comment: This could be due time difference(ie, seconds difference).  Also it is common to think alike when there is a single answer right?.

Comment: @Praveen, of course if there's a single answer people will think alike. But having 4 answers that say the same thing doesn't benefit anyone. The three later answers that add no information are not useful (which coincidentally is what a downvote represents). Deleting these is the right course of action, but positive scored answers can't be deleted save by mods. So the conundrum is that people will end up tacking on these answers, which get upvotes, and then they can't be cleaned up.

Comment: related: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168). "I would want that questions with 10 or more answers (including deleted ones) have additional UI allowing me to review each of previous answers individually prior to posting my own..."

Answer (score 1):

That can lead to unintended results. Like:

*Answer A* (earlier answer)

> It is called "newsprint"

*Answer B*

> It is called "infopaper"

Second answerer will got warning, even his answer is also right. That is only an example but many different situations can be considered. In longer texts, it is even worse.

StackExchange sites have already some filtering. Like *Low Quality Post* review, which picks answer that have a shorter content and put them in review queue. But even that is not a complete solution to your problem.

In fact it is a harder problem to solve in `english.stackexchange` then in here. Because it is not always possible for a single answer to include all data that can be accepted as a *complete answer* . OP asks for a term that have many answers according to time and location in history.

Answer B and answer D are first answers. Since the answer is true, it is normal for the first answer to get upvotes, but second answer's upvotes are not logical since there is 6 minutes difference between them. Answer A add some historical annotation to his answer.

But I am not one to judge that community since I am not a part of it.

People who got reputation for their answer will be eager to participate more and try to make contribution. So users may think upvoting is a good process to grow community.

#### What to do?

So, you must ask that in that community's meta. Will you upvote all answers that have a truth in content or users must be more selective when upvoting. Voting is private and you can not tell anybody how they must vote. But at least, you can argue this and try to figure out *how a good community member should vote*. Because SX community members **must be free to answer** and their answers should be evaluated by the community, not by **a block of code or program**

Comment: Allow me to be blunt. If it's a typo (newspaper -> nawspaper), then edit. If it is a legitimate misunderstanding, then make a comment. If the comment is disregarded, either edit or post your own answer. This doesn't excuse having 4 answers having the same thing. Nor does it improve SE.

Comment: I guess giving a typo example is a bad idea,  I see it now. Edited to fix it with a better example to show what I mean

Comment: @FallenAngel - A 1 rep user can upvote.  It does not matter that the core of the community will all downvote it.  When a question hits the hot list communities get an influx hundreds of new(or rarely visiting) users and posting opinions with out reading the 10 other answers already there... and up-voting those answers.

Comment: @Chad I am talking about the core users in the community, ones who follow the related site. Low rep users who are also new to StackExchange community may think here is just like other boards or forums and may think upvoting is good if there is some truth or something they like in the answer. Beside that, it is not easy to deal with the upvotes comnig from the users you are talking about.